# Using node names defined by chemfig inside TikZ, introducing negative coordinates changes position of arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I draw an arrow between a node named `bond` (defined inside `\chemfig`) and a node `S` which is below it. Everything seems fine until I introduce any element with a negative `y`-coordinate.

Here is the okay example:

```
%% First MWE
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \node (hydrogen) at (2,1.5) {\chemfig{[:30]H-[@{bond}]H}};
    \node (S) at (2,0.25) {S};
    \draw[->] (bond) -- (S);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces this result:

[image: No problem in this situation]

When I introduce a single line defining a node at `(2,-0.5)` (apparently the problem is the negative coordinate), this happens:

```
%% Second MWE
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \node (hydrogen) at (2,1.5) {\chemfig{[:30]H-[@{bond}]H}};
    \node (S) at (2,0.25) {S};
    \draw[->] (bond) -- (S);
    \node (negative) at (2,-0.5) {"Negative" node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Problematic one]

So apparently creating a new node will mess with the coordinates of the arrow.

I *think* what I am doing is allowed, since `chemfig` manual says:

> This is done by marking the departure and arrival points of the electron movement arrow using
> the syntax "`@{<argument>}`". This syntax allows a `tikz` node to be placed and makes this node accessible outside the argument of the `\chemfig` command

Comment: could you place a sketch of the output you desire

Comment: Considering this example, I would desire the arrow not to be affected by drawing other nodes. So the same as Figure 1, but with the added node at the bottom. Note that I don't need to draw this image in particular (I'm sure there are simpler ways to do that), this is just the minimum example that reproduces this "problem", I am interested in using this in much more complex figure.

Comment: have alook at the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may point you in the right direction-- `chemmove` defines a separate `scope` whereas without it is the same as nesting one `tikzpicture` inside another which leads to errors

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
     {\chemfig{[@{bond}:30]H-[]H}}
\chemmove{
\node[below=1cm of bond] (S) {S};
\draw[->](bond) --(S);
\node[below=2mm of S](negative){Negative node};
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful. The trick is indeed to draw the arrow inside \chemmove{} (and apparently to have the nodes that are not defined by chemfig inside \chemmove{} as well). One thing that I was afraid was that I could not place the molecule as a node inside a tikzpicture, but apparently it does work having everything inside tikzpicture with \chemmove{} inside it. For some reason, standalone class didn't work though (I noticed you used article), but that is not an issue.